# In Ms excel how to avoid default header and footer in page layout view

Tags: excel, office365, excel-2016

In MS Excel If I change from one view to another header is adding as default.how to avoid this

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqigZ.png  In Ms excel sheet , If i changing from one layout(A4) to another layout(legal) Whitespaces is Getting added.How to avoid this by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by "view" settings to "Page layout".
[image]

If you change the setting to "Normal", the Whitespaces will disappear.
[image]
In this setting, what ever "Page Layout" you use, no extra whitespace will be shown.

Hope this can help you.

For default settings, you can open the options:
[image]

Set the default view of the new sheets to "Normal view"
[image]

Comment: Thanks..It worked..But If I change my paper size from a4 to legal again the white spaces is getting created. Is there any other settings in Excel by default we can avoid this headers and footers while opening.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the default settings for new sheets. Hope this solves your issue.